# ViewPager crashing and lagging

Tags: android, crash, android-viewpager, lag

I have a viewPager with 52 images which are taken from an array. The problem is that it was working well, but, I wanted to add something like a frame to each image I have in viewPager, and then, the problems start. When I slide through images, it laggs and at some point crashes. I know that the problem is the size of the pictures, which is almost 1mb for each one, but how should I do it not to lag and crash anymore? How should I edit it, but keep my images the same and make it working properly?
Thanks !!!

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.descoper.rom;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int currentPage = 1;
    private static int NUM_VIEWS = 52;
    Dialog dialog;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private int[] pics = { R.drawable.casapoporului2,
            R.drawable.transfagarasan2, R.drawable.transalpina2,
            R.drawable.balealac2, R.drawable.barajulsiriu2,
            R.drawable.bisericadesublac2, R.drawable.canionulscari2,
            R.drawable.cascadacailor2, R.drawable.cascadaciucas2,
            R.drawable.castelulbran2, R.drawable.castelulcorvinilor2,
            R.drawable.castelulkaroly, R.drawable.castelulpeles,
            R.drawable.castelulsturdza, R.drawable.castelulhuniazilor,
            R.drawable.castrulroman, R.drawable.cazaneledunarii,
            R.drawable.cazinoulconstanta, R.drawable.cetateabastionara,
            R.drawable.cetateafagaras, R.drawable.cetateaprejmer,
            R.drawable.cheilebicazului, R.drawable.centrulvechi,

            R.drawable.cimitirulsapanta, R.drawable.colibita,
            R.drawable.deltadunarii, R.drawable.epavacostinesti,
            R.drawable.focurilevii, R.drawable.hanulancutei,
            R.drawable.insulaovidiu, R.drawable.laculalbastru,
            R.drawable.laculana, R.drawable.laculbeului,
            R.drawable.laculbucura, R.drawable.laculcapra,
            R.drawable.laculrosu, R.drawable.laculvidra,
            R.drawable.laculvulturilor, R.drawable.mocanita,
            R.drawable.parculcraiova, R.drawable.parcultimisoara,
            R.drawable.pesteraghetarul, R.drawable.pesteraursilor,
            R.drawable.piatabrasov, R.drawable.poduldumnezeu,
            R.drawable.salinapraid, R.drawable.salinaturda,
            R.drawable.shighisoara, R.drawable.sarmisegetuzaregia,
            R.drawable.sfinxulbucegi, R.drawable.sibiu,
            R.drawable.vulcaniinoroiosi };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        PagerTitleStrip Title = (PagerTitleStrip) pager
                .findViewById(R.id.titlestrip);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/cd.ttf");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < Title.getChildCount(); counter++) {

            if (Title.getChildAt(counter) instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) Title.getChildAt(counter)).setTypeface(font);
                ((TextView) Title.getChildAt(counter)).setTextSize(15);
            }

        }

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position + 1;
            }
        });

        pager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
                // do transformation here
                page.setRotationY(position * -30);
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        protected static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 0;
        protected static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 0;
        String[] title = { "Casa poporului", "Transfagarasan", "Transalpina",
                "Balea Lac", "Barajul Siriu", "Biserica de sub lac",
                "Canionul Sapte scari", "Cascada Cailor", "Cascada Ciucas",
                "Castelul Bran", "Castelul Corvinilor", "Castelul Karoly",
                "Castelul Peles", "Castelul Sturdza", "Castelul Huniazilor",
                "Castelul Roman", "Cazanele Dunarii", "Cazinoul din Constanta",
                "Cetatea Bastioara", "Cetatea Fagaras",
                "Biserica fortificata de la Prejmer", "Cheile Bicazului", "Centrul vechi din Bucuresti",
                "Cimitirul vesel din Sapanta", "Lacul Colibita",
                "Delta Dunarii", "Epava din Costinesti", "Focurile Vii",
                "Hanul Ancutei", "Insula Ovidiu", "Lacul Albastru",
                "Lacul Sfanta Ana", "Lacul ochiul Beiului", "Lacul Bucura",
                "Lacul Capra", "Lacul Rosu", "Lacul Vidra", "Lacul Vulturilor",
                "Mocanita din Maramures", "Parcul Nicolae Romanov din Craiova",
                "Piata Operei din Timisoara", "Pestera Scarisoara",
                "Pestera Ursilor", "Piata Sfatului din Brasov",
                "Podul lui Dumnezeu", "Salina Praid", "Salina Turda",
                "Cetatea Sighisoara", "Cetatea Sarmizegetusa",
                "Sfinxul din Bucegi", "Piata mare din Sibiu",
                "Vulcanii Noroiosi" };

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return title[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_VIEWS;
        }

        /**
         * Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible
         * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
         * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
         * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
         * 
         * @param container
         *            The containing View in which the page will be shown.
         * @param position
         *            The page position to be instantiated.
         * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not
         *         need to be a View, but can be some other container of the
         *         page.
         */
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int position) {
            ImageView view = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            view.setImageResource(pics[position]);

            final ImageView img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            img4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent g1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Galerie.class);
                    startActivity(g1);

                }
            });

            final ImageView img6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            img6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent r = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Romania.class);
                    startActivity(r);

                }
            });

            final ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            img3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int width = size.x;
                    int height = size.y;

                    myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
                    myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();

                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager.setResource(position);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Wallpaper-ul a fost setat cu succes!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });

            final ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    switch (currentPage) {
                    case 1:
                        Intent m1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Maps.class);
                        startActivity(m1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Romania.class);
                        startActivity(i2);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                }
            });

            final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    switch (currentPage) {
                    case 1:

                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cp.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent i2 = new Intent();
                        i2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                        i2.setData(Uri
                                .parse("http://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transalpina"));
                        startActivity(i2);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                }
            });

            final ImageView img5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            img5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("message/rfc822");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                            new String[] { "cicedea.andrei@yahoo.com" });
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent
                                .createChooser(i,
                                        "Trimite-mi un email cu parerea ta. Multumesc !"));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    }

                }
            });

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

            return view;
        }

        /**
         * Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for
         * removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
         * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
         * 
         * @param container
         *            The containing View from which the page will be removed.
         * @param position
         *            The page position to be removed.
         * @param object
         *            The same object that was returned by
         *            {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
         */
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((ImageView) view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        /**
         * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed. At
         * this point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been
         * added or removed from the container as appropriate.
         * 
         * @param container
         *            The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
         *            page views.
         */
        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried optimizing your images using jpgoptimiser.com and tinypng.com to make the file size smaller?

Comment: We cannot help you debug the problem without seeing the crash logs. Post them here.

Comment: I'm not having crash logs because it laggs only on real device, in emulator works perfect, but don't know why..